# Creating groups using data.table

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table, graphing

The working dataset looks like:

```
library('data.table')
df <- data.table(Name = c("a","a","b","b","c","c","d","d","e","e","f","f"),
                 Y = sample(1:30,12),
                 X = sample(1:30,12))

df
    Name  Y  X
 1:    a 14 23
 2:    a 19 18
 3:    b 10 16
 4:    b 23 11
 5:    c  2 12
 6:    c 12 24
 7:    d  8 14
 8:    d 26  2
 9:    e 16 26
10:    e  6  4
11:    f 29 28
12:    f 28 30
```

What I eventually want is to make graph by groups (based on `Name`) for comparison:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(X, Y)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(. ~ Name)
```

Since the actual dataset contains much more observations and `grp`. The ggplot I am creating takes too much time to process and the final graph is unreadable (`grp` > 300). I am planning to re-group the data with limited number of observations and graph them separately (for example, graph 10 groups each time).

So the final dataset should looks like:

```
    Name  Y  X grp level
 1:    a 14 23   1     1
 2:    a 19 18   1     1
 3:    b 10 16   2     1
 4:    b 23 11   2     1
 5:    c  2 12   3     1
 6:    c 12 24   3     1
 7:    d  8 14   4     2
 8:    d 26  2   4     2
 9:    e 16 26   5     2
10:    e  6  4   5     2
11:    f 29 28   6     2
12:    f 28 30   6     2
```

and then I can perform the graphing based on the new group `level`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(X, Y)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(. ~ level)
```

In the above illustration, I created the `grp` simply by:

```
df[, grp := .GRP, by = Name]
```

The question now is how to create the `level` group automatically based on `grp` (I have to create `grp` rather than using `Name` directly as basis since, in the original dataset, there is no patterns in `Name`)?

I tried something like:

```
setkey(df, grp)
i <- 1
j <- 1
while(i < 4 ) {
  df[levels(factor(grp)) == (i:i+2), level := j]
  i <- i + 2
  j <- j + 1
}
```

It does not work well as I need. Could anyone give me some advice how to address this problem? I am really stuck here. I guess there could be a simple way to do this, maybe I don't even need to create the `level` group and can create the separate graphing directly by other means?

Comment: `level` is just `grp` `?cut` into chunks of 3, right?

Comment: @rawr yes, I just give an example there. In the illustration, `grp` has 6 levels, I just want to reduce it to 2 levels, each `level` contains 1~3 levels in `grp`.

Comment: so `df[, level := as.numeric(cut(grp, breaks = 2))]` ?

Comment: well... it works as I want! Fancy! My first time know the `cut` command. I will vote for your answer if you want to post it as an answer. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* there are only a few groups, the `fct_collapse()` function from the `forcats` package can be used. It allows to collapse factor levels into manually defined groups easily.

By, this the new variable `level` can be created directly without making a detour over group numbers and `cut()`. And, the levels can be assigned meaningful labels.

```
library('data.table')
df <- data.table(Name = rep(letters[1:6], each = 2),
                 Y = sample(1:30,12),
                 X = sample(1:30,12))
df[, level := forcats::fct_collapse(Name, "a-c" = letters[1:3], "d-e" = letters[4:6])]
df
#    Name  Y  X level
# 1:    a 11 13   a-c
# 2:    a 29 12   a-c
# 3:    b 16  5   a-c
# 4:    b 12  6   a-c
# 5:    c 25 28   a-c
# 6:    c 27 11   a-c
# 7:    d  5  9   d-e
# 8:    d 23 20   d-e
# 9:    e 13 26   d-e
#10:    e 17 19   d-e
#11:    f 19  8   d-e
#12:    f 22  3   d-e
```

---

However, the OP mentioned that there are many groups 
(`df[, uniqueN(Name)] > 300`) and that he wants *to re-group the data with limited number of observations*. Using `cut()` in the way proposed in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803023/creating-groups-using-data-table#comment61180830_36803023) may lead to unsatisfactory results.

To demonstrate this we need to create a larger sample data set of 100 rows:

```
N <- 100
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.table(Name = sample(letters, N, replace = TRUE),
                 Y = sample(seq.int(3*N), N),
                 X = sample(seq.int(3*N), N))
df
```

Note that `set.seed()` is used to make the data reproducible.

Now, the number of unique values of `Name` (which corresponds to OP's `grp`) is split in 6 levels and plotted in facets (following [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803023/creating-groups-using-data-table#comment61180830_36803023)):

```
n_lvls <- 6
df[, level := as.numeric(cut(as.integer(factor(Name)), breaks = n_lvls))] 
ggplot(df, aes(X, Y)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(. ~ level)
```

[image]

Here, facet 3 contains only a few data points while other facets appear quite crowded.

---

To overcome this, the levels can be arranged to contain approximately *the same number of data points* instead of the same number of factor levels:

```
lvls <- df[, .N, by = Name][order(-N), level := cut(cumsum(N), n_lvls, labels = FALSE)]
df <- lvls[df, on = "Name"]

ggplot(df, aes(X, Y)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(. ~ level)
```

[image]

Now, the observations are more evenly distributed among the facets.

The code counts the number of observations per `Name`, sorts in descending order of `N`, uses `cut()` on the cumulative sum of observations to create a data.table `lvls` ofthe new levels. Finally, the new levels are right joined with the original data set `df`.